# Create indicator matrix from two arrays in Python Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Given two vectors, I would like to create an indicator matrix. For example, given `a=np.array([5,5,3,4,4,4])`, and `b=np.array([5,4,3])`, the result should be

```
   5 4 3

5  1 0 0
5  1 0 0
3  0 0 1
4  0 1 0
4  0 1 0
4  0 1 0
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(a[:,None]==b).astype(int)
```

Sample run -

```
In [104]: a
Out[104]: array([5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4])

In [105]: b
Out[105]: array([5, 4, 3])

In [106]: (a[:,None]==b).astype(int)
Out[106]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

If by simplest, you meant compact, here's a modified one to do the type conversion -

```
In [107]: (a[:,None]==b)*1
Out[107]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

**Explanation :** `None` is an alias for [`numpy.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis), which is used to add a new axis (axis with `length=1`). So, in this case, with `a[:,None]` we get a `2D` version of `a`. There are various other ways to have this `2D` version, `a.reshape(-1,1)` being one of those. This allows for `broadcasting` when compared against `1D` `b`, resulting in a 2D array of matches, a boolean array. The final step is conversion to an `int` array.

Step-by-step run -

```
In [141]: a
Out[141]: array([5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4])

In [142]: b
Out[142]: array([5, 4, 3])

In [143]: a[:,None]
Out[143]: 
array([[5],
       [5],
       [3],
       [4],
       [4],
       [4]])

In [144]: a[:,None] == b
Out[144]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

In [145]: (a[:,None] == b).astype(int)
Out[145]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: `a[:,None]` seems to be equivalent to `a.reshape(-1,1)`. Can you explain how this works exactly?

Comment: @David Added few comments into the post. Hope they help!